# how can I multiply +12v and create -12v

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, audio

I want to take a +12V power supply and duplicate it creating

1- +12v out
1- -12v out

easier said than done?

Comment: what else power supply is available? how much current /load are you expecting for the generated dual polarity 12 V?

Comment: What you are looking for are dc/dc converters.

Comment: What power? For low power you can use switched capacitor voltage converter LM7660.

Comment: Less than 1A. Yeah DC/DC converter schematic is what I need!

Comment: Look at 75XX equivalent DC to DC converters from CUI (and a few other companies, some can't go negative), they can be put in positive and negative modes and their easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a switching inverting regulator capable of dealing with +12V at its input and supplying enough current for your application.

However, keep in mind you'll require additional components and that laying out a good PCB may be critical! It will be something like this (the image shows +5V to -5V but the device is capable of +12V to -12V as well):

[image: Inverting converter]

Some devices that you may find useful:

- [LT1617](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/16171f.pdf), 350 mA
- [LT3580](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3580fg.pdf), 2.5 A

You may also like to consider a commercially available pre-assembled board.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like TPS65131-Q1, a positive and negative output
DC-DC converter. Below is an application schematic diagram:

[image: TPS65131-Q1]

Note that this converter can take only 2.7--5.5V on its input while having dual output up to 15V and down to -15V. For this reason you would have to:

1) Choose a more suitable DC-DC converter that has a dual positive/negative output.

2) Step down potential difference from the output of your power supply (+12V). You can use a linear voltage regulator or a simple buck converter. It depends on how much current the load needs. Also, it would be good if this buck converter wouldn't switch at the same frequency as TPS65131-Q1 (minimum 1.25Mhz).